# How to find the URL for a downloaded file on mac os on google chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web-scraping, download

There are a bunch of files that I want to download off a governement website and everytime I try to save the download URL link, it redirects too quickly and the file downloads. I need the URL pattern to write the script to pull hundreds of files.

How can I save this URL or get it from the HTML href argument?

Answer (score 0):

Please right click on link tag, and select "Copy link URL".